# incorrect display of the images height in safari

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, safari

only in safari on mac I have a problem with displaying images at 100% height. In other browsers it works as expected. It is important to me that the carousel column and the text column on the right automatically change height when I add more text. I use bootstrap 4.5.2

```
<div id="audis3" class="row mt-4">
        <!-- Miejsce na karuzelę -->
        <div class="col-md-8 addpadding pl-0">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide h-100" data-interval="false">
                <!-- Wskaźniki (indicators) -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>

                <!-- Slajdy karuzeli -->
                <div class="carousel-inner h-100">
                    <div class="carousel-item active h-100">
                        <img src="car.jpg" alt="Audi S3 - Zdjęcie 1" class="img-fluid custom-carousel-image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item h-100">
                        <img src="car1.jpg" alt="Audi S3 - Zdjęcie 2" class="img-fluid custom-carousel-image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item h-100">
                        <img src="car2.jpg" alt="Audi S3 - Zdjęcie 3" class="img-fluid custom-carousel-image">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Strzałki nawigacyjne -->
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Poprzedni</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Następny</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
            <!-- Miejsce na tytuł i opis po prawej stronie -->
            <div class="col-md-4 adpad">
                <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center h-100">
                    <h2 class="car-title">Audi S3</h2>
                    <!-- Pill Badges w jednej linii z wyśrodkowaniem -->
                    <div class="align-items-center mb-1">
                        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-ultra mr-1"><i class="fa-regular fa-calendar pr-1"></i>&nbsp;2018</span>
                        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-ultra mr-1"><i class="fa-solid fa-fire-flame-simple pr-1"></i>&nbsp; 2.0</span>
                        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-ultra mr-1"><i class="fa-solid fa-shuffle pr-1"></i>&nbsp;Automatyczna</span>
                        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-ultra"><i class="fa-solid fa-gas-pump pr-1"></i>&nbsp;Benzyna</span>
                    </div>
                    <p class="car-description mt-1">Niezwykle dynamiczne auto</p>
                    <!-- Przycisk "Dowiedz się więcej" -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn-learn-more mt-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Sprawdź dostępność</button>
                    <div class="mt-3">
                        <h2 class="rent-info">Dodatkowe informacje</h2>
                        <ul class="rent-info-list">
                            <li><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> Ceny podane w brutto.</li>
                            <li><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> Limit 300 km. na dobę.</li>
                            <li><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> Brak kaucji</li>
                            <li><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> Opłata za przekroczenie limitu kilometrów 2 zł/km.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Cennik -->
<div class="mt-1">
    <h2 class="priceHeader">Cennik</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm price-list">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Ilość dni</th>
                <th scope="col">Cena dobowa</th>
                <th scope="col">Limit kilometrów</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1-2</th>
                <td>60</td>
                <td>300 km</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">3-4</th>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>250 km</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">5-7</th>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>210 km</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Miesiąc</th>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>3 000 km</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
.carousel-item.active img, .carousel-item img {
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I tried change height to auto or inherit